# Scala function results in a scala error FatalError: object ObjectRef does not have a member create"error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I try to define a function for Apache Spark with scala, using databricks notebook.
When I test the functionality all works correct:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
var medians: HashMap[String,Double] = new HashMap()
doubleTypeCols.foreach{ x => medians += (x -> getMedianCol(dfTrain, x))}
```

And I get the correct Map

When I define it as a function, I receive an error:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
def test(cols:Seq[String]):HashMap[String,Double] = {
  var medians: HashMap[String,Double] = new HashMap()
  cols.foreach{ x => medians += (x -> getMedianCol(dfTrain, x))}
  return medians
}
```

results in an "scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: object ObjectRef does not have a member create" error. What is the reason for that? I found some answers, that it could be caused by incompatible versions, but why it only occurs in a function?

Thanks a lot
kumaro

Comment: Just curious: What happens if you do it in an FP manner? `cols.foldLeft(HashMap.empty[String,Double]){case (m,x) => m + (x -> getMedianCol(dfTrain, x)}` Any difference?

Comment: I was curious too and tried it. It works if I Change HashMap to Map. So the Problem is probably that HashMap isn't created correctly.

Comment: I figured out that the Problem occurs as I have to use var for the Hashmap. In the FP style we don't Need to declare the HashMap as var, then it works.